# Complex routing in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create descriptive routes in the NextJs app however I'm struggling with the nextJs file-based routing system.
Intended route in the web is: (/posts/id/mail);
How I do it in the project:

```
Posts
 - index.js
 - [id]
   - mail.js
```

As you can see, I don't have index.js in my [id] folder hence whenever somebody decides to go to /posts/id without '/mail' it is gonna be 404.
So basically my question is: How do I turn mail.js into index.js and make the URL stay the same (/mail at the end).

If there is no way of doing it natively with nextjs I'd also be grateful if you let me know.

Comment: Apparently, only redirect helps in this case

Answer (score 1):

#### catch all

This might not be the way you like it, but you might use a [catch all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes) to hande `[id]` and `mail.js` together in one file.

E.g. if you have a file `[...post].jsx` and call the routes `/someid/mail` or just `/someid` you would have `params.post` to be an array like `[ 'someid', 'mail' ]` or just `[ 'someid' ]`.

#### redirect

Apart from that I also didn't find any way for a folder to be a route on its own without an index file (or any other file), especially for a route like `www.example.com/` (i.e. without an `/index` appended to it). I solved it by using some "unneeded" path `/main` and then redirected that to `/`.

#### As a remark:

I found that the specific route `/index` caused an error in some cases, that's why I've choosen `/main`.

I don't remember exactly, it might be dependent on if you want both routes ('/index' and '/') to be valid and point to the same file (and stay visible in the addressbar), or if only one of them should be valid and redirect to the other. Also in that case my paths came from `getStaticPaths`, not from files.

Comment: Thanks but I ended up creating index.js for each folder and added redirects in getServerSideProps